# Create an Interactive Dice Roller App on Android Developers

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm completing this course https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-build-a-dice-roller-app?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-build-a-dice-roller-app

I have completed the above codelab correctly and matches the solution code on GitHub although I'm receiving a warning which is -> **Prefer `mutableIntStateOf` instead of `mutableStateOf`**

Also, when I move onto the next codelab https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-intro-debugger?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-2-pathway-2%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-intro-debugger I run the Attach Debugger and I receive the following message -> **Unable to start debugger session**

Advice please.

I have tried to fix the issue although no options for this and Android Studio wants me to change the name from **mutableStateOf **to **mutableintStateOf**

I've just noticed that the course material does not match the solution code on GitHub as the course material does not display the Spacer composable although the code I've written in Android Studio contains the Spacer composable.

Thank you in advance.

Written code from the codelab.
Without debugger.
Attach debugger not working.

Tried uploading images, although unable to as your system will not allow for them to display.

Answer (score 0):

`mutableStateOf()` is the generic version that you can use to wrap *any* value.
`mutableIntStateOf()` on the other hand can only wrap an Int. It is more than just a convenience, though, it also improves performance slightly, because the underlying `Int` value is stored as a [primitive `int`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#numbers-representation-on-the-jvm), which prevents it from being auto-unboxed each time it is needed. That is why the compiler suggests that you change it.

Since `mutableIntStateOf()` is a more recent addition to compose, it might be possible that it didn't exist back then when the codelab was created, so they had to use `mutableStateOf()`. In a similar vein, they obviously changed some things in the code on GitHub, without adjusting the code lab.

Nothing to worry, though, in essence it's the same, and by comparing what additional changes were made you can even learn some more!

As to the debugging problem: Have you tried directly installing the app in debug mode by clicking the debug icon right next to the run icon? If you still have problems with this, please create a new question that explains the problem in more detail.

Comment: As I said, you should separate your different problems into separate questions. Create a new one for your debugger problem and make sure to use the proper tags.